# bug in tabu when rowcolors are defined?

Tags: color, tabu

In the following code the vertical separation from cell to the bottom is negative instead of the defined `\tabulinesep=5pt` when `\rowcolor{headcolor}` and and `\rowfont` are defined.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}
  \tabulinesep=5pt
\listfiles
\begin{document}
\colorlet{headcolor}{gray!25}
\begin{tabu} to 0.8\textwidth{X[1,L]X[1,L]}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{headcolor}
    \rowfont[l]{\bfseries}%
     head & head \tabularnewline
    \hline
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column &
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column \\
    \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Here the visual result

[image]

Is this a bug in the tabu package? I contacted the author of tabu, but got no answer in the last days.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\rowcolor` is defined by `colortbl`. So it's an incompatibility between the two packages. You can fix that by using the `tabu` command `\taburowcolors` instead:

```
\colorlet{headcolor}{gray!25}
\begin{tabu} to 0.8\textwidth{X[1,L]X[1,L]}
    \hline
    \taburowcolors 1{headcolor .. headcolor}
    \rowfont[l]{\bfseries}%
     head & head \tabularnewline
    \taburowcolors 1{white .. white}
    \hline
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column &
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column \\
    \hline
\end{tabu}
```

[image: tabu example with colored row]

Comment: Ok, but that is a different command with a different usage. It can  be used to implement the same colors with a different approach. So in my example `\rowcolor` is showing a bug in tabu environments.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work with `\multicolumn` :-(

Answer (score 0):

It's quite odd, but what helped me was to just switch the order of the `\rowcolor` and the `\rowfont` commands, i.e. put the `\rowcolor` command right before the row contents.

So, in your example it should be:

```
...
\begin{tabu} to 0.8\textwidth{X[1,L]X[1,L]}
    \hline
    \rowfont[l]{\bfseries}\rowcolor{headcolor}%
     head & head \tabularnewline
    \hline
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column &
    text which is considerably longer than the width of the column \\
    \hline
\end{tabu}
...
```

After that, `tabu` worked just fine and commands like `\tabulinesep` were displayed correctly for every row.